# Passing variables through environments

Tags: r

I have the following two functions :

```
f1<-function(){
txt<-1234
f2(where="txt")
}

f2<-function(where){
foo<-eval(parse(text = where))*2
return(foo)
}
```

When calling f1(), I would expect it to return 2468. However

```
> f1()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'txt' not found
```

I do not understand why, and specifically why f2 does not know txt. Of course it is not defined in its own environment, but it is defined in the caller environment (in f1), I thought everything defined within f1 should be visible to f2 ?

Of course, if in f1 I have

```
txt<<-1234
```

then

```
> f1()
[1] 2468
```

But I would rather avoid global assignments (in real code, I do not want to have stray global objects...)

So the question is, how can I make txt (defined in f1) visible to f2 ?

Thanks

(and in case you wonder, the real-life f2 is more complex, such that passing the name of a variable makes sense; in any case it is a function written by somebody else on which I have no control, so the solution should come from the f1 side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** The problem is really with `f2`, not with `f1`, so `f2` should be fixed. One would normally define `f2` to pass the environment explicitly.    With this code `f1` would work as is.

```
f2 <- function(where, envir = parent.frame()) {
  eval(parse(text = where), envir = envir)*2` .  
}
```

**2)** The following is less desirable; however, if we did not have control over `f2` then we could do this in `f1` (where now `f2` is unchanged from the question):

```
f1 <- function() {
   txt <- 1234 
   environment(f2) <- environment()
   f2(where = "txt")
}
```

**3)** A third option is to define f2 within f1:

```
f1 <- function(){
   f2 <- function(where) eval(parse(text = where))*2
   txt <- 1234
   f2(where = "txt")
}
f1()
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the `envir` argument in `eval` as `parent.frame()`

```
f2<-function(where){
    foo<-eval(parse(text = where), envir= parent.frame())*2
   return(foo)
 }

f1()
#[1] 2468
```

Comment: It does work. But is there a solution on the f1 side (see the last sentence in my original question, I have no control on f2 in the actual code)? And as an aside -- why ? I thought the default behaviour was to look in all the environments upstream (from local, to the calling env, to global...) ?

Comment: And besides -- the help file for eval() goes "Usage:eval(expr, envir = parent.frame() ....", so parent.frame() should be the default, and there should be no need to explicitly specify it ?